# Spring boot Angular routing

Tags: spring-boot, angular-routing

I am merging Spring boot backend and Angular frontend into one deployeable app. The issue i am having is that when i access the base url and then navigate through the application, it works just fine while trying to access a specific url (routing involved) yields not found exception (404) for any Angular related resource. I think it is  because Spring is trying to find a request mapping for the requested resource and do not delegate it to Angular for routing.
Is there some configuration which would for requested urls starting with /rest/ try to find a mapped resource, while for other just letting the Angular handle it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?